# Exception generated for is.readObject. why?

Tags: java, android

I have a game that regularly saves the game current status to a file (by writing a serialized object to a file).The user can resume  the game later on and it will read that object  and build the game from there.

This seems to be working fine, but sometimes I get this exception

```
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:98)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.nextTC(ObjectInputStream.java:506)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:778)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
        at com.myGame.GameState.loadFromFile
        at com.myGame.GameState.loadGame
```

And here is the loadFromFile code

```
         try {
    FileInputStream fis = mActivity.openFileInput(fileName);
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    stateDetails = (StateDetails)is.readObject();//exception is generated here

    is.close();
    fis.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    MyApplication.SWERR(e);
}
```

I don't understand why would this happen. Its one time object saving and reading. No loops involved to reach end of file. Why would it be generated?
Any help is appreciated ........thanks

Edit: this is how I do the saving

```
FileOutputStream fos = mActivity.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(stateDetails);
            os.flush();
            fos.flush();
            os.close();
            fos.close();
```

Comment: Have you added any fields to StateDetails or to any of the variables being read in?

Comment: What do you mean by added any fields? StatDetails is a class that has 15 member variables (fields)

Comment: Are you always closing your stream when you write to the file? That could be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This seems to be working fine, but sometimes I get this exception

Try to use this approach:

```
try {
   FileInputStream fis = mActivity.openFileInput(fileName);
   ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
   while(true) {
      try {
         stateDetails = (StateDetails) is.readObject();
      }
      catch(EOFException ex) {
          is.close();
          break;     
      }
   }
}
catch (Exception e) {
   MyApplication.SWERR(e);
}
```

I had similar problem and i solved it by code above. But always you need to make sure that:

- don't call `readObject()` twice
- close always `ObjectOutputStream` immediately after writing is done
- if you are writing more objects at first you need to write their
  count via `writeInt(<value>)` and then before reading call `getInt()` and read objects
  in loop

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. So for second point, do you mean that I dont need to do a flush? (Just close right away). I dont write more than one object  but what  I do is that after every 10 sec I call the code above which opens the file and re-write to it and close. I dont think I need writeInt for it eh?

Comment: @Snake so you can call `flush()` as well. and no, if you want to write only one object you don't need to call `writeInt()`.

Comment: Actually looking at the code you had above, i dont see the point behind looping over! There is only one object written and it should be read once

Answer (score 0):

[EOFException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) means you are trying to read past the end of the file. Plausible causes could be:

1. Problem while writing the file, or possible corruption of the file itself.
2. It can be zero length file that shouldn't be zero length.
3. You might be reading a file, other than what was wrote.

My suggestion would be, put a check for [is.available()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#available%28%29) and try reading the object.

Comment: Check my edit above for update. Why would I run into any of the errors above?Suggestion for debugging?